# Перенаправление на другой домен

Tags: php

Дан чужой сайт - `чужой_сайт.ру/скрипт.пхп?user=1&password=123456`

Я бы хотел бы сделать такой скрипт, `мой_сайт.ру/скрипт.пхп?user=1&password=123456`

При переходе сюда => `мой_сайт.ру/скрипт.пхп?user=1&password=123456`, чтобы открывался чужой сайт (`чужой_сайт.ру/скрипт.пхп?user=1&password=123456`).

Граберы не предлагать. Вопрос: возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 4):

Да. Почитайте про mod_rewrite
В 
мойсайт.ру
ложим .htaccess и пишем там:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://чужойсайт.ру/$1 [L,P,QSA]
```

В итоге все реквесты будут идти на чужойсайт, но в адрессной строке будет отображатся ваш сайт.

Answer (score 2):

Может вот так:

```
$ref=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if ($ref!='') $ref='?'.$ref;
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://нужный адрес'.$ref);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://moysayt.цц/?login=asdasd&password=12313